# Getting error of list indices must be integer or slices not string after applying lambda function

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis

In the below code I'm applying a positive and negative sentiment and neutral sentiment as per polarity score using a function `fetch_sentiment_using_SIA`

```
df['sentiments'] = df['text_clean'].apply(fetch_sentiment_using_SIA)
```

But it is not working how to resolve it?

Comment: What is not working, are u getting any error please include that in your question.

Comment: Yes im getting error in  above code as list and indices must be int & slices not str...